# Showing $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ implies $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Show that $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ implies $x \equiv 1 \pmod p$ or $x \equiv (p-1)\pmod p$ for every prime $p$.

I understand one might be able to prove on of the converses but I have no clue as to how to proceed with it and any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Caution: This is the third (or fourth) PSQ from this user within three hours.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco what's a PSQ?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel:  I asked the same thing.  A "Problem Statement Question".  Hope that helps!

Comment: @RobertLewis I thought at first "public service question"...

Comment: $(x^2 - 1) = (x-1)(x-2) = k*p$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel:  I like your definition better! ;)

Comment: You should use the $\LaTeX$ code `a \equiv b \pmod{n}` to produce $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$.

Comment: It might be interesting for you to know that every polynomial of degree $ n $ a coefficients in a field (in your case the field is the finite field of $ p $ elements with $ p $ prime number) admits $n$ roots in some extensión of the field. To see that $ x ^ 2 = 1 $ admits two roots $ \ ± 1 $ (note that $ p-1 = -1 $ because $ p = 0 $ is sufficient to operate with $(-1) ^ 2$ and with $ 1 ^ 2 $.

Comment: Do you know [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)?

Comment: It does have something to do with unique factorization of any polynomial as a product of irreducibles; I think this might be mentioned. After all, $X^2+1=0$ has infinitely many solutions in the quaternions.

Answer (score 3):

If

$x^2 \equiv 1 \mod p, \tag 1$

then

$(x - 1)(x + 1) \equiv x^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \mod p; \tag 2$

therefore,

$p \mid (x - 1)(x + 1); \tag 3$

now since $p$ is prime we have

$[p \mid (x - 1)] \vee [p \mid (x + 1)]; \tag 4$

if $p \mid (x - 1)$, then

$x - 1 \equiv 0 \mod p \Longrightarrow x \equiv 1 \mod p; \tag 5$

if this fails, that is, if $p \not \mid (x - 1)$, then we must have

$p \mid (x + 1) \Longrightarrow x + 1 \equiv 0 \mod p \Longrightarrow x \equiv -1 \mod p. \tag 6$

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use the fact that because $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain, for a polynomial $(x-a_1)\dots(x-a_n) \equiv 0$ (mod $p$), then we must have for some $i$ that $(x-a_i) \equiv 0$ (mod $p$), from which the desired result then follows. The fact that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain follows from Euclid's lemma that if $p|ab$, then either $p|a$ or $p|b$, and a quick argument by induction gives us what we need to prove the result.